# Nodejs memory leak when running MSSQL queries

Tags: sql-server, node.js, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, tedious

I have a script in NodeJS that runs MSSQL queries in a loop, and process each row asynchronously, but the script keeps crashing with the following error message after running for just a few seconds:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I have tried using the tedious module and the mssql module for running queries against a MSSQL database, and the result is the same. If I remove the database interaction and hard-code the database result, the script does NOT ever crash. It appears the queries are causing a memory leak. I have included the following module to log when garbage collection occurs, and it is only running at the very start of the script:

```
require('nodefly-gcinfo').onGC(function(usage, type, flags){
   console.log("GC Event Occurred");
   console.log("Heap After GC:",usage, type, flags);
});
```

How can I get around the memory leak or cause garbage collection to run? After I am done with the query results, I am calling "delete variableName" to try to force garbage collection.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This bug was resolved by upgrading from Nodejs version 0.10.30 to version 0.10.33.

```
apt-get upgrade nodejs
```